# Dotnet Core Web API escapes backslahes unintentionally

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an endpoint that accepts json data of the `currentPassword`, `newPassword` and `newPasswordConfirmation`.

I've run into a problem, as I want to accept literal backslashes (`\`) in passwords, they have to be passed in, but they get escaped by Web API validation.

I guess I'm missing so attribute on the C# class, but I haven't found it.

*Request:*

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:44343/1/NO/User/123/Password/Change" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-Api-Key: secret-key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"currentPassword\": \"bla\hej\.%", \"newPassword\": \"blabla\", \"newPasswordConfirmation\": \"blabla\"}"
```

*Response:*

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|3876e18a-40326202f78c6022.",
  "errors": {
    "$.currentPassword": [
      "'h' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.currentPassword | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 26."
    ]
  }
}
```

*Model I deserialize to*:

```
    public class BasePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NewPasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChangePasswordModel : BasePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If acceptting literal backslashes (\) in passwords, you need to use

```
\\  (Backslash character)
```

Other special character

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
```

Then the bakend can receive double backslash, because the particularity of the backslash, it must appear in pairs. The backslash in the database can be compared directly after it becomes a string.

---

The another method is to put the data into the **formdata**, it can serilize all charater.

```
public IActionResult change([FromForm]ChangePasswordModel changePasswordModel)
    {
        //...
        return Ok(changePasswordModel);
    }
```

Comment: So all API consumers must replace \ with \\ with before sending the json? That's not a good solution for me.

Comment: @Max, except this, one backslash does not comply with the w3c protocol.

Comment: @Max, another method is to send the formdata to the bakend.

Comment: @Max: What you're saying is that you want something *a bit like JSON, but not actually JSON*. What you're sending at the moment isn't valid JSON. Any client using a JSON library won't have this problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, please elaborate that. The client sends REST requests using the same model as used in the backend (shared as NuGet). You mean that the model should be manually serialized by the consumer, before passing it in the API request?

Comment: @Max: If the client is sending valid JSON, it shouldn't be a problem. But a backslash followed by an h as shown in your curl request is not valid JSON. If you could show the JSON actually sent by your client, instead of a curl request, that would make it easier to help you... at the moment it *feels* like you're just being misled by an inappropriate curl request. If you want to represent a backslash in a string within JSON text, it needs to be escaped - it's as simple as that. (But the client shouldn't need to do that manually, unless it's *manually* creating JSON.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for the explanation. After escaping the strings in the client with @ it works as intended. Another problem was that the password encryption algorithm removed double `\`, so the password check didn't work, but that's another issue.

Comment: @Max: That sounds like you're still building the JSON manually - I'd *strongly* advise you to use a library to either serialize a data model, or serialize anonymous types etc. You really don't want to have to handle the JSON part yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I thought that I did that here: `request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));`

Comment: @Max: Well it's hard to know what your code was before or what you've changed, as you haven't shown any of that code in the question But if you're using `JsonConvert`, you shouldn't have ended up with any invalid JSON.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, you're right. The problem with the invalid JSON was actually when I was calling the API through Swagger. However, it still doesn't work because of the password encryption algorithm. Thanks for your support, doubt solved.